# setInterval and Switch Between Divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slideshow, setinterval

I'm trying to switch between divs at an interval, but also be able to stop it in order to include the ability to switch on command with an arrow button on the screen. (Like a slideshow of divs with an arrow to switch immediately.)

Therefore, I cannot use .delay(), as it cannot be stopped, so I'm trying to use .setTimeout, but I'm failing miserably. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
var divs = $('div[id^="Frame"]').hide(),
i = 0;

(function cycle() { 
divs.eq(i).fadeIn(1000)
         .setTimeout(function(){divs.eq(i).fadeOut(1000, cycle);},2000);        


i = ++i % divs.length; // increment i, 
                       //   and reset to 0 when it equals divs.length
})();
```

Comment: You can't use `setTimeout` like that.  It doesn't work that way.  `setTimeout` needs to be called on its own, it's not part of a chain.

Comment: Look at http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp for the explanation of setTimeout() and clearTimeout().

Comment: It's not a method of jQuery to add to that @RocketHazmat

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but here is some code which will fadein/fadeout the divs and you have a chance to stop the process:

```
var divs = $('div[id^="Frame"]').hide(), 
    i = 0,
    currentDiv = null,
    interval = null;

var stopFading = function() {
    clearTimeout(interval);
}
var showDiv = function() {
    if(currentDiv) {
        currentDiv.fadeOut(1000, function() {
            currentDiv = null;
            showDiv();
        });
    } else {
        currentDiv = divs.eq(i);
        currentDiv.fadeIn(1000, function() {
            interval = setTimeout(showDiv, 2000);
        });
        i += 1;
        if(i > divs.length) i = 0;
    }
}
showDiv();
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't taken a look to see if the rest of your code is working, but the immediate error is that `setTimeout` is not chainable.  So the code should look like this...

**EDIT -- SHOULD WORK**

The other issue was that the increment of `i` needed to be done in the `setTimeout` otherwise, `i` would be incremented before the function ran

http://jsfiddle.net/RJe86/1/

```
var divs = $('div[id^="Frame"]').hide(),
i = 0;

(function cycle() { 
    divs.eq(i).fadeIn(1000,function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
           divs.eq(i).fadeOut(1000, cycle);
           i = ++i % divs.length; // increment i, 
                       //   and reset to 0 when it equals divs.length
        },2000); 
    });       
})();
```

Comment: So, it worked, but now it is not hiding each div after it fades out :( Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Yes, the increment needs to be done inside the `setTimeout`.  I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/asudiVuy/3/edit)**

**JS**:

```
var H = $('#FrameHolder'),
    D = $('#Frame > div'),
    B = $('#Button'),
    n = D.length,
    f = 400, // fade time
    p = 2500,// pause
    c = 0,   // counter
    i;       // interval

function loop(){
  i = setInterval(function(){B.click();},p);
}loop();

H.hover(function(e){
  var mEnt = e.type.match('t');
  B.stop().fadeTo(f,!!mEnt);
  return mEnt?clearInterval(i):loop();
});
B.click(function(){
  D.stop().fadeOut(f).eq(++c%n).fadeIn(f);
});
```

**HTML**:

```
<div id="FrameHolder">  
  <div id="Frame">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
  </div>
  <div id="Button"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
#FrameHolder{
  position:relative;
  margin:0 auto;
  width:400px;
  height:300px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
#frame{

}
#Frame > div{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:276px;
  width:400px;height:300px;
}
#Frame > div + div{
  display:none; /* hide all but 1st */
}

#Button{
  cursor:pointer;
  position:absolute;
  width:60px;
  height:60px;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  border-radius:50%;
  right:20px;
  top:50%;
  margin-top:-30px;
  display:none;
}
```